# Limit 2 digits only from a hash code

Tags: php, hash, echo

I have this `$img['hash']` which is a long hash code 32-64 digits a09806aa003033128f44d5fd4c56786b (as an example)
Is there any way in php to pull only the 1st two digits (a0)

```
<?php
$cdb = new PDO('mysql:dbname=xxx;host=localhost', 'xxx', 'xxx');

foreach ($cdb->query("SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY posted DESC LIMIT 9") AS $img)
{
    echo '<a style="position: relative; display: block; height: 200px;" href="/booru/post/view/' . $img['id'] . '" target="_blank">
          <img src="booru/timthumb.php?src=thumbs/' . $img['hash'] . '&h=125&w=125" style="border-style: none"/>
           </a> 
        ';
}
```

Sorry I should of added some more info I need to keep the $img['hash'] also

So like this

```
                <img src="booru/timthumb.php?src=thumbs/' . $img['hash'] . '/Here/&h=125&w=125" width="125px" style="border-style: none"/>
```

I need to add it where the  "/here/" is

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to get a substring of a string, in this case your hash:

```
$twofirst = substr($img['hash'], 0, 2);
```

Comment: The answer still applies. Simply use the `$twofirst` variable where you wrote `Here`. Using `substr` doesn't modify your original string, so `$img['hash']` stays the same.

Comment: Thanks am very new to php so sorry about that :) so like this http://pastebin.com/CCrWEJ58 thanks for the help

Comment: Yes that works but it stops SELECT * FROM images ORDER BY posted DESC LIMIT 9") only one is showing

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
substr($img['hash'], 0, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use php's substr method (http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and output:

```
substr($img['hash'), 0, 2)
```

Which will output the first 2 digits, starting at index 0, of the $img['hash'] string.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use [substr](http://php.net/substr):

```
echo '<img src="...' . substr($img['hash'], 0, 2) . '" />';
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can use substr
http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

```
substr(img['hash'], 0, 2)
```

should do the trick